# Which File reading Writing IO class to use and when?

Tags: java, io, nio

As we all know with Java comes the very complicated list of IO classes plus there is another thing called NIO.

1. I was wondering if there is any thumb rule that could explain the situations and best IO to use for the problem( considering Web application in mind ).
2. I always get confused which one to use when, another query is How should I remember the implementation of all these classes. It get confusing all the time

Comment: Me also looking for the same, But all in all you will remember after you know the functionality and usage of most important ones :)

Comment: The gist of your question is right, but your wording of it is a bit verbose and wandering.  You have answers below and you haven't accepted any.  I would scrap the second part of your question.   It leaves your question as too broad and easily provides a reason for mods to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Difference between IO vs NIO:**

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                          IO                           |                            NIO(New IO)                            |
+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Stream oriented                                       | Channels/Buffers oriented                                         |
| Thread Blocking IO(Synchronous)                       | Non Thread blocking IO(Asynchronous i.e notification based)       |
| Read or Write can do one byte/char at a time.         | Channel is bidirectional.                                         |
| Readers are for read only, Writers are for write only | Channel can read and write byte buffer(not char buffer).          |
| Buffer creates in JVM heap memory.                    | Buffer can be outside or in-memory of JVM.                        |
| Charset is limited ot UTF-8.                          | Charset support expanded to UTF-16 and more.                      |
|                                                       | "Selectors" allows a single thread to handle multiple Channel's.) |
+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

- java.io package was introduced in JDK 1.0 (January 23, 1996)
- [`java.nio`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) (NIO stands for non-blocking I/O) API was introduced with the J2SE 1.4 (February 6, 2002)
- An extension to NIO that offers a new file system API, called NIO.2, was released with Java SE 7 (July 28, 2011), it includes new sub-package [`java.nio.file`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) under `java.nio`
- Blocking call: Control returns only when the call completes
- Non blocking call(often refers to [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O#Polling)): Control returns immediately.

[Enhancements in Java I/O](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/enhancements.html#7)

Comment: The question is about file I/O, and there is no non-blocking. File I/O in Java, and 'non-blocking' and 'asynchronous' are two different things, not two names for the same thing. `java.io` is not limited to one byte/char at a time, or to UTF-8.

Comment: And there is no caching in NIO.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't so mysterious.

- `RandomAccessFile` when you need random access (rare)
- `FileWriter` when you're writing text
- `FileChannel` when you need NIO
- `FileOutputStream` in all other cases.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: use java.io classes for applications likely to be performing a low number of concurrent I/O operations.  Use java.nio classes for applications likely to serve a high number of concurrrent I/O operations.

The I/O operations can be anything from TCP connections to your web server (ex: concurrent HTTP requests) to file system operations for performing file reads or a disk search to database connections on the backend.

An application using java.io with a single concurrent I/O operation will typicallly outperform one using java.nio.

In a server with a high number of concurrent I/O operations, java.nio allows efficient interleaving of I/O among clients.  It also has the opportunity to use resources more efficiently by reducing the number of threads and thus memory and context switching overhead.

The API of java.nio classes is more complex given their evented nature.

In a web application you should check if your container (Tomcat, Jetty, etc.) or your web framework (Play, JSF, etc.) has an API for dealing with files.  Unmanaged File I/O from a web application can introduce additional security vulnerabilities.

Tomcat allows you to switch to an NIO backend (be aware of possible behavior changes like compression and content-lengrh if you write directly to respond streams):
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/aio.html

Comment: You have this back to front. NIO makes it possible to *reduce* the number of threads. The isn't really such a thing as a single-threaded Java application, but a server that is built with java.io and java.net will certainly be multi-threaded, and will use many more threads than one built using java.nio.

Comment: Good point.  I hope I have addressed your concerns in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Java IO for reading:

The FileInputStream class makes it possible to read the contents of a file as a stream of bytes. The FileReader class makes it possible to read the contents of a file as a stream of characters. The RandomAccessFile class in the Java IO API allows you to move around a file and read from it or write to it as you please.